# MySQL thinks subquery is derived when it is not!

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

```
EXPLAIN SELECT node_id 
          FROM node 
         WHERE person_id IN (SELECT person_id 
                               FROM user 
                              WHERE is_locked = 0);
```

Results in MySql telling me the subquery is derived.  But it's not!

(I know this could easily be re-written as a JOIN, but I want to know why MySQL thinks this is a dependent subquery.)

Comment: I'm no MySQL expert, but I've read several people who are here at Stackoverflow state that MySQL has a blind spot in its query optimizer in exactly this situation.

Comment: +1 Because MySQL is really bad at detecting a dependent subquery and there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: In my understanding of the terms, the sub-select is derived (a resulting table is derived from the query) but not correlated (the sub-query does not use any data from outside of itself), also known as dependent. That means that it should only run once, not once per row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the MySQL Query Optimizer. It would seem that, if the table in the subquery matches the table in the main query, it is considered a dependent subquery even if it obviously should not be, and there's no easy fix. Sorry; go for the join.

Comment: This a real shame because there are now gazillions of MySQL-only (or primarily) users who think there's something inherently non-performant about this construct when, in fact, it's just a failure of MySQL specifically.

Comment: I am just floored that MySQL can reach version 5 with a bug this basic and serious.