# Rails join with max condition

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, max

Given these two models

```
class Article < AR::Base
  belongs_to :tag

  default_scope order('id DESC')
end

class Tag < AR::Base
  has_many :articles

  scope :featured, order(:ordering).limit(5)
end
```

I'm trying to join these two tables in a manner such I can retrieve a list of featured tags and for each of them the latest article in that tag with a single query, something like

```
Tag.featured.each do |tag|
  p tag.name
  p tag.articles.first.title # this will fetch the article in the tag with the highest id
end
```

Written in this way this code has the [(n+1) query problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), I'm trying to optimize it because it will be run very frequently. I've excluded an `includes` call in the `featured` scope because it will load all the `Article` in the first 5 tags (a lot of articles...)

In plain old SQL I can join this two tables using a query like this

```
SELECT tag_id, MAX(id) FROM articles GROUP BY tag_id
# or in Rails
Article.select('MAX(id), tag_id').group(:tag_id)
+--------+---------+
| tag_id | MAX(id) |
+--------+---------+
| 14     | 26787   |
...
| 1      | 27854   |
| 5      | 27780   |
| 0      | 10953   |
+--------+---------+
```

as a join table I can retrieve all the data with a single query.

How to port that in Rails and ActiveRecord?

**update**

The full query i need executed in AR context is

```
SELECT a.*, t.*
FROM tags t
JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS latest, tag_id FROM articles GROUP BY tag_id) j ON j.tag_id = t.id
JOIN articles p ON j.latest = a.id
LIMIT 5
```

I tried `AR#find_by_sql` method with the latest query, I get the correct resultset but then I cannot navigate through objects

```
sql = '...' # This holds the previous query
Tag.find_by_sql(sql).first.class
=> "Tag"
Tag.find_by_sql(sql).first.articles.first
=> nil # why???
```

**update 2**

Tried also with

```
Tag.joins('JOIN ... all my query join part here ...').first.articles.first
=> nil
```

However I noticed that I can use my articles field directly as Tag fields, i.e. I can write

```
Tag.find_by_sql(...).first.title # where title is a field of Article class
Tag.joins(...).first.title # where title is a field of Article class
```

but obviously I can not call `Article` instance methods.

Comment: I'm going to self-accept my own answer because of no other answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a partial solution to my issue. I could fetch the needed record with two queries and still having data loaded as AR objects:

```
# This will fetch the needed article ids
ids = Article.select('MAX(id) as max_id').group(:tag_id).map(&:max_id)
# This return the top tags each one with the article needed in articles.first
Tag.includes(:articles).where('article.id IN (?)', ids).limit(5).each do |t|
  t.name # gives the tag name
  t.articles # gives [<#Article...>] i.e. an array with a single article
end
```

Rails will do three queries:

1. one to select the ids
2. one to select the `Tags` ids in returned_ids of point 1
3. the latest to fetch with a (very strange) `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to fetch data from the two tables, using `WHERE a.id IN (ids) AND t.id IN (returned_ids)` as condition

I can't go with a WHERE condition like

```
where('article.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) from articles)')
```

because [MySQL has a bug and it would think the subquery is derived](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278743/mysql-thinks-subquery-is-derived-when-it-is-not). It seems that it [will be fixed in 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065062/improve-mysql-query-with-in-subquery/7065099#7065099).

Still looking for better answers, maybe a JOIN such as the one in my question which loads AR objects.